# MongoDB Aggregation+Cursor coupled with JS Generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, async-await

It is the first time I am using Generators in JavaScript (Node.js). I just wanted someone to validate if the implementation is correct.
If not, please suggest a better way.

So, there are 2 questions here:

1. Is the generators based implementation optimized. And before being optimized, is it correct. (I am getting the results, however, just wanted to understand it from the blocking/non-blocking perspective).
2. I am making 10 API calls using node-fetch and collecting the promises in an array. If I need to deploy this on AWS Lambda, is it okay if I do not use Promise.all(array) and simply return irrespective of whether the API calls are successful or not? Anyway I do not care about the response. I just trigger the API.

Requirements:

1. Host a Node.js function that talks to MongoDB using Mongoose driver on AWS Lambda.
2. Fetch 10000 documents from MongoDB.
3. The documents have the following schema. The _id key holds a String value of length 163:

```
{
 _id: "cSKhwtczH4QV7zM-43wKH:APA91bF678GW3-EEe8YGt3l1kbSpGJ286IIY2VjImfCL036rPugMkudEUPbtcQsC"
}
```

3. I am interested in the value of _ids and I am able to process just 1000 _ids at a time.
4. Those are put into an array and an API call is made. Hence, for 10000 _ids, I need to make 10 API calls with 10 of those arrays.

Implementation I did using Node.js Generators:

```
async function* generatorFunction() {
    await connectMongo();
    const cursor = Model.aggregate([
        //... some pipeline here
    ]).cursor();
    const GROUP_LIMIT = 1000;
    let newGroup = [];
    for await (const doc of cursor) {
        if (newGroup.length == GROUP_LIMIT) {
            yield newGroup;
            newGroup = [];
        }
        newGroup.push(doc._id);
    }
    yield newGroup;
    await disconnectMongo();
}

const gen = generatorFunction();

(async () => {
    const promises = [];
    for await (const newGroup of gen) {
        // POST request using node-fetch
        // Ignore the syntax
        promises.push(fetch('API', { body: { newGroup } }));
    }
    // Do I need to do this?
    // Or can this be skipped?
    // I do not care about the response anyway...
    // I just need to trigger the API and forget...
    await Promise.all(promises);
    return {
        success: true,
    };
})();
```